# log into wordpress with webinject

Tags: wordpress, monitoring

I am trying to create a script log into the admin section of wordpress and then check for updates, I already did this for drupal using the example mentioned here:

```
<case
    id="1"
    description1="short description"
    description2="long description"
    method="post"
    url="http://myserver/test/login.jsp"
    postbody="username=corey&password=welcome"
    verifypositive="verify this string exists"
    verifynegative="verify this string does not exist"
    logrequest="yes"
    logresponse="yes"
    sleep="3"
/>
```

and also a comment here http://drupal.org/node/147413#comment-1269222

I am however stuck with the  postbody part, it wont log in the admin page.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't get this to work but someone made a nagios check that works

Answer (score 0):

I can  tell you about the testcases we created for atlassian suite, maybe the example will help you, this case is the one we created for CONFLUENCE

**TESTDATA FILE**

confluence_Basic_AD_Login_testdata.xml  (it first login to webapp and then checks login by checking the dashboard)

```
 <testcases repeat="1">

 <case
         id="1"
         description="Get Confluence Login Page"
         method="post"
         url="https://confluence.company.com/login.action"
         postbody="os_username=conflumin&os_password=conflumin123"
         errormessage="Unable to connect to the login page of Confluence"
         verifypositive="Username"
         logrequest="yes"
         logresponse="yes"
 />

 <case
         id="2"
         description="Authentication by AD to Confluence"
         url="https://confluence.company.com/dashboard.action"
         verifypositive="Dashboard"
         errormessage="Unable to authenticate user in Confluence"
         logrequest="yes"
         logresponse="yes"

 />

 </testcases>
```

**CONFIG FILE**

file:  confluence_Basic_AD_Login_config.xml

```
   <testcasefile>confluence_Basic_AD_Login_testdata.xml</testcasefile>
   <useragent>WebInject Application Tester</useragent>
   <timeout>10</timeout>
   <globaltimeout>30</globaltimeout>
   <reporttype>nagios</reporttype>
```

That's all, and the check works with NagiosXI.
Hope it helps you.

karina